# predicted values for polr generate only a small subset of response values

Tags: r, statistics, ordinal-classification

I want to create a model for some ordinal categorical response data with values from 0 to 10, having 3 predictors being categorical and numeric. I am therefore using, among others, the function `MASS::polr`. Here a dummy example:

```
data <- data.frame(response = factor(sample.int(11, size = 300, replace = TRUE), 
                                     levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
                                                "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), 
                                     ordered = TRUE),
                   gender = rep(0:1, 300),
                   pred2 = sample.int(11, size = 300, replace = TRUE),
                   age = rpois(300, 30))
```

The problem is that when I use the predict function with type "class" and I compare the predicted data to the real outcomes, the model seems to take into account only some of the values from the response variable, in particular, the most frequent ones from the training:

```
index <- createDataPartition(data$response, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)

dummy_train <- data[index, ]
dummy_test <- data[-index, ]

> table(dummy_train$response)
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
 37 31 48 21 66 37 31 35 45 30 42
```

```
model_polr <- polr(response ~ gender + pred2 + age, data = dummy_train, Hess = TRUE)
predict_polr <- predict(model_polr, newdata = dummy_test, type = "class")

> summary(predict_polr)
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11 
  0   0   0   0 177   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I am a bit lost because I see that these are the outcomes with the highest probability, but I don't see any utility in this type of prediction. Am I missing something in the way of setting the predicted data?

Comment: This is more suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), but the short answer is that since your simulated data has no correlation between the predictors and the response, the model makes similar predictions for every observation, with the probabilities proportional to their overall proportions in the training data set.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BenBolker for the suggestion. I put here simulated data with basically no correlation because I can't share my real data, but if I understand correctly, what you mean applies to my real case too and it would just mean that the predictors chosen for describing the model are too poorly correlated to the data to make a meaningful prediction, did I get you correctly?